# EF 6.2 Unique constraints with multiple (overlapping) columns is not generated correctly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I use Fluent API to configure my unique constraints (EF 6.2) and have the following configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TagDTO>().HasIndex(p => new { p.SiteId, p.InputId, p.Name }).IsUnique();
modelBuilder.Entity<TagDTO>().HasIndex(p => new { p.SiteId, p.InputId, p.SqlColumn }).IsUnique();
```

This way I can configure a unique constraint using multiple columns. The `Name` and `SqlColumn` must be unqiue if the `InputId` and `SiteId` are the same.

I cannot configure these using attributes because of inhertitance in my model. Fluent API must be used to configure this.

Now the problem is the following: the geverated migration looks like this:

```
...
.Index(t => new { t.SiteId, t.InputId, t.Name }, unique: true)
.Index(t => t.SqlColumn, unique: true, name: "IX_SiteId_InputId_SqlColumn")
...
```

And when executing this migration only the `Name` is correctly configured in MS SQL. The `SqlColumn` does not have a unique constraint with multiple columns. When switching the two Fluent API lines the `SqlColumn`will be correct and the `Name` incorrect.

Why is the index on `SqlColumn`not configured with an object? Is it because of overlapping columns (`SiteId`and `InputId`). Changing it manually in SQL works so it is possible.

Is this a bug in EF? Has anyone a solution for this problem?

`SiteId`: ForeignKey to table Site.
`InputId`: ForeignKey to table Input.
`Name` & `SqlColumn`: NOT primary key, just string columns

Thanks you.

EDIT: Changing the migration code manually does work but this cannot be a solution.

```
...
.Index(t => new { t.SiteId, t.InputId, t.Name }, unique: true)
.Index(t => new { t.SiteId, t.InputId, t.SqlColumn }, unique: true)
...
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in EF6 Migrations.  Manually fixing the migration is a workaround, but please post a repro to https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for the reply, I will post it as an issue as soon as I can. (and if nobody proves I made a mistake somewhere in my configuration)

Comment: You didn't make a mistake.  The issue repro's based on what you posted.